# Method not triggered from antlr generated java code

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I'm trying to count the method declarations in my java code **A.java** using Antlr produced parser and lexer for Java obtained from [Github](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java8). The code that I'm trying is as follows:

### TestListener.java

```
package antlrjavaparser;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

public class TestListener extends Java8BaseListener{
    static int methodCount=0;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("src/main/java/A.java");
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(in);
         if (in == null){
             System.err.println("Unable to find test file.");
         }
        Java8Lexer lex = new Java8Lexer(input);
        
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
        Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(tokens);

        ParseTree tree = null;
        tree = parser.compilationUnit();
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        Java8BaseListener listener = new Java8BaseListener();
        walker.walk(listener, tree);
        printTokens(lex);

        System.out.println(methodCount);
        
        }

    private static void printTokens(Java8Lexer lex) {
        // Print tokens
        Token token = null;
     
        while ((token = lex.nextToken()) != null) {
            
            if (token.getType() == Token.EOF) {
                break;
            }
            if (token.getChannel() == Token.HIDDEN_CHANNEL) {
                continue;
                
            }
        System.out.println("Token: [" + token.getText() + "] Type:[" + token.getType() + "]");

        }

        lex.reset();
    }
    @Override
    public void enterMethodDeclaration(Java8Parser.MethodDeclarationContext ctx) { 
        methodCount++;
    }
}
```

`methodCount` prints `0` every time. **A.java** is a very simple java class containing a few methods. I've tried overriding multiple methods from `Java8BaseListener` to see if any of them is triggered at all but it looks like they're not. Am I using antlr wrong? Is there anything wrong with the way I'm using `walker`? I just started working on this two days ago so I don't really know antlr too well. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Java8BaseListener listener = new Java8BaseListener();
```

Here you're instantiating the base listener, which does nothing. You should be instantiating your subclass of it. So:

```
Java8BaseListener listener = new TestListener();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!